# AngularJS HTTP request response data out

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post, imgur

I need to put response data from an HTTP post request into another variable, but when reaching the variable it is undefined. Thanks

```
$http({
     headers:{
          'Authorization': 'Client-ID y24w6y5645243rw'
     },
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload',
     data:{
          'image': self.images[i],
          'type':'base64'
     }
     }).then(function(response){
          console.log(response.data.data.link)
          $scope.link = response.data.data.link;
}); //end http request
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code which is used to access the variable?

Comment: Apart from mentioning where you are trying to access this, can you also let us know whether the image is successfully stored in the server using the post and whether console.log(response.data.data.link) has any data?

Comment: How about  result of  console.log(response)?